# Creating custom FunctionQuery in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to create a custom Solr FunctionQuery so that I would be able to get the actual length of field (in terms). The results might look like this :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":8,
    "params":{
      "q":"python",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"title,score,[features efi.query=python store=myfeature_store]",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":793,"start":0,"maxScore":0.33828905,"docs":[
      {
        "title":"Newest 'python' Questions - Stack Overflow",
        "score":0.33828905,
        "[features]":"titleLength=5"},
      ]
  }}
```

The only helpful link I'm able to find is [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-write-custom-solr). But it does not explain the topic very well. I'm very new to Solr, so step-wise procedure will be helpful.

**EDIT**

I've created a js script called `count.js` as follows:

```
function WordCount(str) { 
  return str.split(" ").length;
}

function processAdd(cmd) {
    doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
    var title = doc.getFieldValue("title");
    var count = WordCount(title);
    doc.setField("title_count", count);
    logger.info("count-script#count: title_count=" + count);
}

function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

Also, I've added following entries in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">script</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="script">
    <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="script">count.js</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I've a few questions now:

1. For this to work, do I have to re-index the documents using Nutch ?
2. How to check if it's working? Will a simple solr query work like `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Update Request Processor. Quite a few ways to do it.

Check out the [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_4_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html)

You basically clone your field and do a count on it. But this will work only when your source field is multi-valued. That is, before feeding it to Solr, you tokenize them. You configure this in your SolrConfig.xml

```
    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="word-counter">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">title</str>
    <str name="dest">title_count</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">title_count</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">title_count</str>
    <int name="value">0</int>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

But remember, this requires that you have "title" as multi-valued which may not be ideal. You can have an additional field something like "title_multi" and mask your process.

Alternatively, you can use a [ScriptUpdateProcessor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/ScriptUpdateProcessor) and do perform your counting logic in Javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "source field as multi-valued"? Also, will it give counts of character or words ?

Comment: `"title": ["Newest","python", "Questions", "Stack", "Overflow"]` This is multi-valued. It counts the words. Please read the documentation that I have linked to.

Comment: But my filed will be like `"title":"Newest 'python' Questions - Stack Overflow"`. Will it work for it ?

Comment: Not unless you pre-process your data like suggested or write an "word counter" script using the ScriptUpdateProcessor.

Comment: I was trying to use `updateRequestProcessorChain` as suggested by you. How to check if it's working correctly? What will be the request I need to post ?

Comment: If you have indexed them as multi-valued like `"title": ["Newest","python", "Questions", "Stack", "Overflow"]`, then simply search for that record and you should see a field "title_count" with 5 as it's value, in your result set.

Comment: Will changing `<field name="title" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>` to `<field name="title" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>` in `nutch/conf/schema.xml` and recrawling work ?

Comment: Well, if you are using Nutch to crawl your data then you have little room to pre-process the data before you send it to Solr. In that case your best best would be the ScriptUpdateProcessor. You should be able to count the words in your title with few lines of script.

Comment: I've crated a simple `js` function for this. Although, I've a few questions. I've edited my question.

Comment: They seem correct. Make sure you have a "title_count" field defined in your schema and perform a full re-crawl. The query that you posted should return "title_count" if it is available. Post back if you see errors in your logs while indexing.